# Sublime on Save Build exclude pattern

Tags: regex, sublimetext, regex-negation, sublime-text-plugin

I installed a Sublime plugin called "SublimeOnSaveBuild" which compiles my sass files while saving. But now I'm going to work with more than just one file.

The plugin offers a filter function which is checking if the filename matches the pattern `\\.(sass|less|scss)$`.
But i need a pattern which matches any file that is **not** preceded by an underscore.
I tried `\\(?!_).*.(sass|less|scss)$` but this doesn't work.
Any ideas what is wrong with this pattern?

The result should be that `file.sass` gets compiled but not `_file.sass`.

Comment: what are the double slaches use for ?

Comment: I don't know. I just copied them from the pattern which came with the plugin.

Comment: I just tried it without them and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Exactly... You could also replace them with `^` which defines the begining of a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this patern should work: `^(?<!_)[a-z-]*\.(sass|less|scss)$`

This part: `(?<=_)` is called positive lookbehind assertion.

You can do some tests here: https://regex101.com/r/gN8uX1/2

Answer (score 2):

As the answer of streetturtle did not work for me, i found another solution on https://joshuawinn.com/ignore-sass-and-less-partials-starting-with-underscore-when-using-sublimeonsavebuild/ which is

```
(/|\\\\|^)(?!_)(\\w+)\\.(css|js|sass|less|scss)$
```